# Bluetooth Health Device Profile

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, embedded

I want to send data from a weight scale to any bluetooth device.I have a sample android code which talks with medical device using HDP sink profile but I don't have the actual medical device to test. My question is can we implement Bluetooth Health Device Profile between laptop and mobile, where our laptop can act as source and Android mobile as Sink.Or is there any way to test?.

Comment: What have you tried? None of us can help you unless I have something to work with, in particular a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A great way to explain this is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Also, do check out the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: @impinball the MCVE requirement only applies to debugging questions, which this is not.

Comment: @SustasLauti - the possibility of using a laptop to emulate a USB peripheral depends on the unspecified software stack and operating system running on the laptop, as well as the bluetooth interface hardware.  Try searching for an example of implementing some other bluetooth peripheral.  Also decide if you are trying to emulate a classic bluetooth device or a BLE one.